# Are horadric caches bound to the act they were acquired from?

Tags: diablo-iii

Since the latest patches, horadric caches have been dropping the same quality of loot regardless of difficulty.

What I would like to know is that if each horadric cache acquired has its loot table bound to the specific act they were acquired from.

For example, say I want to farm for Gloves of Worship, an act2 bounty-only legendary. Would I be able to acquire it from an act4 horadric cache but that was opened in Act2?

Or would I have to, instead, farm bounties from Act2 or Act4 only?

Comment: Short answer: yes, they are tied to the act that generated them